# Can I use a loop to label multiplex inputs in circuitikz with origin 0?

Tags: circuitikz, loops

I have a number of multiplexer drawings and I want to label the inputs starting at 0 rather than one. I am using a loop and the  code example below works fine:

```
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
\tikzset{
            mux 10by2/.style={muxdemux,muxdemux def={Lh=10, NL=10, Rh=8,NB=0,NT=2, w=2}                     }
            }
   \node [mux 10by2](MuxA) at (0,0){MUX};
   \foreach \x in {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}
   \node [right, font=\tiny] at ($(MuxA.lpin \x)+(0.2,0)$) {\x};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

This works fine however it labels the inputs 1 to 10 rather than 0 to 9. I need the origin at 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See `pgfmanual sec 89 Repeating Things`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
\tikzset{
            mux 10by2/.style={muxdemux,muxdemux def={Lh=10, NL=10, Rh=8,NB=0,NT=2, w=2}                     }
            }
   \node [mux 10by2](MuxA) at (0,0){MUX};
   \foreach \x [count=\c] in {0,...,9}
   \node [right, font=\tiny] at ($(MuxA.lpin \c)+(0.2,0)$) {\x};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```